# JobPosting Structured Data

Tags: google-search, google-search-platform

There seems to be a logical conflict in the definition of the JobPosting structured data here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-postings. HiringOrganization is listed as a required property, and this requirement is corroborated by the fact that the structured data testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) will not pop a "preview" button for a JobPosting unless the HiringOrganization property is both present and populated (more on that in a moment).

However, on that same page, above, it's listed that an acceptable/valid posting example is "Recruiter ad with an apply flow where the company is unspecified. This is acceptable because the role is well-defined and the company does exist, even if it is not revealed. In this case, *the hiringOrganization markup must be blank* (see Misrepresentation of self, product, service, job or company)." [emphasis mine]

I tried both leaving the hiringOrganization property out entirely and including the element but having blank values or whitespace values for the name property or even just having an empty set of quotes and no child properties. In any of those cases, the preview button will not appear on the test tool (which makes me think that I also will not get a rich snippet in search results <--- this is the primary reason I'm attempting to add the structured data).

Can anyone confirm or deny my assumption about the correlation between "no preview in the structured data test" and "no rich snippet in search results?" Also, if anyone has any additional information on this apparent discrepancy and/or how to resolve it, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Google has removed that sentence from their page and all references to "recruiters".

It's subjective but that removal would imply to me that it is now an entirely required field and that they only want to accept job postings from the companies for which the roles are with. I.e. no recruiters.

Comment: The sentence hasn't been removed. It's just collapsed by default inside the "valid examples" node.